# bigint is not supporting in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, postgresql

I have made function in postgresql supporting JSON. It works fine when there is not bigint data in insert query but it fails while there is bigint data in column check_number.there is bigint datatype in database table.
my function in pgsql is as follows:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transactions.post_transaction(
    tran_ json,
    detail_ json,
    share_tran_ json)
  RETURNS bigint[] AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE r           transactions.tran_type;
    DECLARE _tran_id    bigint;
    DECLARE _tran_ids   bigint[];
BEGIN

    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::transactions.tran_type, $1)
    LOOP

        INSERT INTO transactions.transactions(
            office_id, tran_date, value_date, book_name, collector_id, 
            total_amount, teller_id, is_auto_payment, is_compounded, is_flagged, instrument_id, 
            instrument_number, verification_status_id, verified_by_user_id, audit_user_id, collection_sheet_id,
            loan_receipt_id, loan_reimburse_id, cash_transfer_id, remittance_id, standing_instruction_id, ibt_tran_id
        )
        SELECT r.office_id, r.tran_date, r.value_date, r.book_name, r.collector_id, 
            r.total_amount, r.teller_id, r.is_auto_payment, r.is_compounded, false, r.instrument_id, 
            r.instrument_number, r.verification_status_id, r.verified_by_user_id, r.teller_id, r.collection_sheet_id,
            r.loan_receipt_id, r.loan_reimburse_id, r.cash_transfer_id, r.remittance_id, r.standing_instruction_id, r.ibt_tran_id;

        SELECT CURRVAL('transactions.transactions_tran_id_seq') INTO _tran_id;
        IF _tran_ids IS NULL THEN
        _tran_ids := array[_tran_id];

        ELSE
            _tran_ids := _tran_ids || _tran_id;
        END IF;


        INSERT INTO transactions.transaction_details(
            tran_id, account_number_id, loan_id, gl_account_id, share_account_id, repository_id,is_interest, 
            slip_number, check_number, is_loan_collection, debit, credit, statement_reference, audit_user_id, deno_id, ref_dep_ac_id)

        SELECT _tran_id, td.account_number_id, td.loan_id, td.gl_account_id, td.share_account_id, td.repository_id, td.is_interest, 
            td.slip_number, td.check_number, td.is_loan_collection, td.debit, td.credit, td.statement_reference, r.teller_id, td.deno_id, td.ref_dep_ac_id
        FROM json_populate_recordset(null::transactions.tran_detail_type, $2) td
        WHERE td.office_id = r.office_id;

        INSERT INTO transactions.share_transaction(tran_id, share_account_id, kitta_from, kitta_to, audit_user_id)
        SELECT tran_id, share_account_id, kitta_from, kitta_to, audit_user_id
        FROM json_populate_recordset(null::transactions.share_tran_type, null) s
        WHERE s.office_id = r.office_id;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN _tran_ids;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION transactions.post_transaction(json, json, json)
  OWNER TO postgres;}
```

Json returns as follows query

SELECT * FROM transactions.post_transaction
 ((('[{"audit_user_id":13000057,"book_name":"Withdrawal","cash_transfer_id":null,"collection_sheet_id":null,"collector_id":15000089,"flagged_by_user_id":null,
 "ibt_tran_id":null,"instrument_id":null,"instrument_number":null,"is_auto_payment":null,"is_compounded":null,"is_flagged":false,"loan_receipt_id":null,
 "loan_reimburse_id":null,"office_id":3,"reference_number":"8001061713","remittance_id":null,"standing_instruction_id":null,"statement_reference":null,
 "teller_id":13000057,"total_amount":15000,"tran_date":"4/22/2016 12:00:00 AM","tran_id":0,"value_date":"4/22/2016 12:00:00 AM","verification_status_id":1,
 "verified_by_user_id":0},{"audit_user_id":13000057,"book_name":"Withdrawal","cash_transfer_id":null,"collection_sheet_id":null,"collector_id":15000089,
 "flagged_by_user_id":null,"ibt_tran_id":null,"instrument_id":null,"instrument_number":null,"is_auto_payment":null,"is_compounded":null,"is_flagged":false,
 "loan_receipt_id":null,"loan_reimburse_id":null,"office_id":16,"reference_number":"8001061713","remittance_id":null,"standing_instruction_id":null,"statement_reference":null,
 "teller_id":13000057,"total_amount":15000,"tran_date":"4/22/2016 12:00:00 AM","tran_id":0,"value_date":"4/22/2016 12:00:00 AM","verification_status_id":1,
 "verified_by_user_id":0}]')), (('[{"account_duration":null,"account_number_id":13019905,"audit_user_id":13000057,"check_number":8001061713,"credit":null,
 "debit":15000,"decimal_value":0,"deno_id":null,"gl_account_id":4849,"interest_rate":null,"is_interest":false,"is_loan_collection":false,"is_overdraft":null,
 "loan_days":null,"loan_id":null,"loan_receipt_type":null,"office_id":3,"ref_dep_ac_id":null,"repository_id":null,"share_account_id":null,"slip_number":null,
 "statement_reference":"by self","tran_id":0,"transaction_detail_id":0},{"account_duration":null,"account_number_id":null,"audit_user_id":13000057,"check_number":null,
 "credit":15000,"debit":null,"decimal_value":0,"deno_id":null,"gl_account_id":4797,"interest_rate":null,"is_interest":false,"is_loan_collection":false,"is_overdraft":null,
 "loan_days":null,"loan_id":null,"loan_receipt_type":null,"office_id":3,"ref_dep_ac_id":null,"repository_id":null,"share_account_id":null,"slip_number":null,
 "statement_reference":"by self","tran_id":0,"transaction_detail_id":0},{"account_duration":null,"account_number_id":null,"audit_user_id":13000057,
 "check_number":null,"credit":null,"debit":15000,"decimal_value":0,"deno_id":null,"gl_account_id":4801,"interest_rate":null,"is_interest":false,
 "is_loan_collection":false,"is_overdraft":null,"loan_days":null,"loan_id":null,"loan_receipt_type":null,"office_id":16,"ref_dep_ac_id":13019905,"repository_id":null,
 "share_account_id":null,"slip_number":null,"statement_reference":"by self","tran_id":0,"transaction_detail_id":0},{"account_duration":null,"account_number_id":null,
 "audit_user_id":13000057,"check_number":null,"credit":15000,"debit":null,"decimal_value":0,"deno_id":null,"gl_account_id":4781,"interest_rate":null,
 "is_interest":false,"is_loan_collection":false,"is_overdraft":null,"loan_days":null,"loan_id":null,"loan_receipt_type":null,"office_id":16,"ref_dep_ac_id":null
 ,"repository_id":79,"share_account_id":null,"slip_number":null,"statement_reference":"by self","tran_id":0,"transaction_detail_id":0}]')), (('null')));

Comment: What's the error message that you're seeing ?

Comment: ERROR:  value "8001061713" is out of range for type integer. this error is in check_number column how can i define it is bigint datatype

Comment: What is the type defined in `transactions.transaction_details` ? You are inserting check_number in that table, that might be your problem.

Comment: There is bigint datatype in column check_number but when i manually insert same data by insert query it works fine but problems from json. I only want to know how to define bigint data type in json.

Comment: There is no bigint datatype in json, you need to treat them as string as long as you're dealing with json :(

Comment: where do i define long in above function?help me please

Comment: I think that your function is ok, that't your input json that's not. Can you add it to the question ?

Comment: I have added json in above question sir.

Comment: Yep, `"check_number":8001061713`should be `"check_number":"8001061713"`

Comment: same problem sir ERROR:  value "8001061713" is out of range for type integer

Comment: Ok so the problem might be the `json_populate_recordset(null::transactions.tran_detail_type, $2)` as this is the only place where you use this specific json data. So this means that in `transactions.tran_detail_type`, `check_number`is declared as an integer and not a bigint.

Comment: Ok I added an answer and I was thinking about it twice and you might not need to use `"check_number":"8001061713"` as `"check_number":8001061713` might work. Be careful that your bigint is not truncated though.

Comment: Thank you Clement sir finally it works i did as you have guided me. thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so the problem might be the `json_populate_recordset(null::transactions.tran_detail_type, $2)` as this is the only place where you use this specific json data.

So this means that in `transactions.tran_detail_type`, `check_number`is declared as an integer and not a bigint.

This should fix it if I got it right:

```
ALTER TABLE transactions.tran_detail_type ALTER COLUMN check_number TYPE bigint;
```